# How to parallelize accumulative probability function with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to make more efficient via parallelizing my code that calculates the accumulative probability function. I have a `vector<double>` of radii called r and I need to count how many elements there are with a radius bigger than a given one > R. In addition, I need to calculate the accumulative probability function for the volume.

The code I have is the following one:

```
int i, j;
double aux, contar, contar1, aux;
vector<double> r, contador, contador1, vol,
for (i = 0; i != r.size() - 1; i++)
{
    aux = r[i];
    contador[i] = 0;
    contador1[i] = 0; 
    contar = 0;
    contar1 = 0;
    vol[i] = 0.0;
    for (j = 0; j != r.size() - 1; j++)
    {
        if(aux <= r[j])
        {
            contar++;
            #pragma omp atomic write
            vol[i] = vol[i] + 4.0 * 3.141592653589793 * r[j] * r[j] * r[j] / 3.0;
        }
    if(aux==r[j])
    {
       contar1++;
    }
    }
    #pragma omp atomic write
    contador[i]=contar;
    #pragma omp atomic write
    contador1[i]=contar1;
}
```

but it's not efficient at all. Any help in order to make it more efficient with OpenMP?

Comment: Your code has invalid syntax and doesn't have any parallel regions.

Comment: which invalid syntax? and it does have parallel regions. #pragma omp appears 3 times in the code

Comment: You need to add a parallel section with the directive #pragma omp parallel

Comment: @Lane but where could I add it? Because if I don't do it properly the results may change

Comment: The  #pragma omp atomic is designed to go within parallel regions and prevent multiple threads from accessing the indicated region within the  #pragma omp atomic (it does not create any parallel region, quite the opposite)

Comment: @Lane I understand, but how could I parallelize the code?

Comment: The parallel section must be declared preferably in the outermost loop and you must declare as private all the variables that you do not want to be shared between the threads or declare all the needed variables inside the loop. I think the easiest thing to do is parallelize the first loop and declare all the variables inside the loop and remove all the atomics, since each thread executes entirely the second loop,

Comment: @elenafer that depends on how you would implement such parallelization, but within this code, you can use a `#pragma omp for` before your first for statement. Maybe you can use this [reference guides](https://www.openmp.org/resources/refguides/)

Comment: You need to choose a parallelization strategy first. I would recommend to split the work into bulks (with the part of initial data) , calculate the result for every bulk locally and then merge the results; this would help you avoid the extensive usage of expensive atomic operations. All work in the bulks should be done in parallel. Of course, you may just use brute force parallelization of all iterations of the outer loop, but this will cost you much in sync up with atomic operations since each loop will write at the same resulting variable, creating a strong concurrency.

Comment: @Lane this doesn't seem to work. I added the line: #pragma omp parallel for private(aux, r, contador, contador1, contar, vol) 
 before for(i=0...) loop and I get all the vectors with null values

Comment: @DamirTenishev This would help llittle as I need to work with aprox 11 millions data. The difference would be 121000000000000 data - 60500000000000 ... I would like a more dramatic change

Comment: @Lane what about using count_if function? I don't know if I could use if for vol[i]

Comment: @CcmU I get segmentation fault when I use #pragma omp parallel for. Any help?

Comment: Make an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), please.

Comment: The provided code does not compile, and even if it would, it will crash a runtime. Please provide at least a correct sequential code (still, you can add a try of a non-working parallel code aside if you want). Beside this, please not that is is much better tu declare variables with the shortest possible scope when you are dealing with parallel code (in order to avoid race condition bugs later).

Comment: @elenafer, for me your comment seems irrelevant to my answer. Bulking helps especially when you have a lot of data. I don't understand what exactly "121000000000000 data - 60500000000000" means, seems to be just random numbers. Anyway, if you make your code working in parallel (that's what you are asking about), why do you expect to have more speedup than the number of CPUs you have? Please, make your question more specific so that people could help.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I want to make my code faster by parallelizing. I don't want to change it if it is not goint to make a significant change on running rime. The numbers I gave you are a example of how many times I have to go through a loop in the case I have 11 millions data. With my code it's the first numebr, with your suggestion, it's the second number, and it's not a significant change for me. So I want to parallelize it but I don't know how to do it

Comment: @elenafer I can't say much, without the code's output, nor I can help without knowing *how* you want to parallelize your code. You have to consider how you'd have to split data between threads or, eventually, how to instruct the master thread or the slaver ones how to communicate between each other. Just to say few things. I recommend you to look at the referenced guide, to have a better understand of the topic in general

Comment: @CcmU I only need to calculate the cumulative probability function of some data stored in a vector, that's all, but I am completely new in c++ and I need some help

Comment: @elenafer, well, two things here. (1) First doesn't relate to parallelization. You have O(n^2) complexity, you could improve this if you sort your array (with any parallel sort) and then calculate the sum of volumes for "last n-i elements", this will speed up to approx O(n^1.2) or O(n*log(n)).  (2) You could reverse your algorithm so that it writes different vol[i] in parallel (see scatter memory access) to avoid bottleneck on atomic write. If you implement (1) correctly you will be able to avoid atomic writes and so (2).

Comment: @DamirTenishev How could I do the part of "then calculate the sum of volumes for las n-i elements"?? I know how to order them in an efficient way, but I still don't know how to make the two loops more efficient

Comment: When you have the r array sorted by radius of the circles (ascending), the number of circles bigger than this one is n-0-1. Now about the sum of volumes: create an array sum_of_volumes. The last its value is the volume of the last circle, the last but one is the sum of last two, next one from the end is sum of last 3 (each time you need to add one volume to the prev sum). When array is ready, for each circle you know the sum of the volumes of the circles which bigger than this one, just taking the value of i+1 element from that sum array. Could require some adjustments if radiuses could repeat

Comment: @DamirTenishev I don't undertand the part "the number of circles bigger than this one is n-0-1"

Comment: @elenafer, misprint, n-i-1, where n number of circles in the array and i - index of the current circle.